# access to a member of a struct (pointer) with the use of double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

hey I am trying to create a program in which I am trying store elements from one array to another with the use of a pointer to pointer but the problem is that is caused undefined behavior I believe that the problem is that I do not pass the elements in members with a proper way
I know it is a vague way of doing this but It is in only for practising reasons

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
 typedef struct student{
 
    char *name;
    int *number;    
 
 
 }T;
 
int main(void) {

char array[10][100]={"araaaa","bbgt","gffkghgh"};   

T arr[10][100];
T *p;
T **p1;
p=&arr[0][0];
p1=&p;


int i=0;

for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
{   p=arr[i];
    strcpy((*p1)->name,array[i]);
    }

/*******print_elements*************/

for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
{   p=arr[i];
    printf("\n the elements are %s",(*p1)-> name);
}


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
strcpy ((*p1)->name, array[i]);
```

`(*p1)->name` is an uninitialised pointer.  What happens, therefore, is in the lap of the gods.

The easiest fix is to modify your `student` structure such that `name` is a buffer, rather than a pointer.  At the same time, change `number` to an `int`, rather than a pointer to an `int`::

```
typedef struct student{
    char name [100];
    int number;    
} T;
```

---

If you want to keep `name` as a pointer then you have to allocate some memory before you store your string in it.  This should work:

```
(*p1)->name = strdup (array[i]);
```

Don't forget to `free` the memory when done.

Comment: I have done this but I would like to practise with a pointer member 

so It does not an another way??

Answer (score 0):

`T` is made of of two pointers, this first one points to a string of characters in memory.

`arr` is a 2D array that is allocated to store a total of 1000 T structures.

`arr[i]` would reference a 1D array of T structures within `arr`

`*p1` would essentially be `arr[i]`, since dereferencing p1 gives you `p`, which was just set to `arr[i]`.  So, that is not a pointer to a `T` structure, but to an array of `T` structures. Forcing the cast will likely give you a reference to the first `T` structure in that row, however.

`->name` This value is never set. You allocated an array, but "name" is a pointer to memory, not an array of characters, so '->name' is undefined.

I think you need to change `arr` to be a single dimension array. You aren't using 90% of it.

And, you need to initialize every `T` struct in that array. You can use `malloc` or `strdup`, and then remember to free them all. Or, set the struct to  use an array instead.